# Data Not Getting Ordered BY in my Report

Tags: c#, sql-order-by, reportviewer

I have a dataset which gets populated using a query with a OrderBy Statement, i  then am trying to use that dataset for display on my report but the data is not getting Ordered by Correctly.

The Query Used to Populate the DataSet

```
SELECT        Month, TotalWeek, Date, [SumOfRM Lbs Saved], [SumOfRM Savings $]
FROM            RMSavingsByDate
ORDER BY Date
```

[image: Result of the Query]

[image: Result of the same query on my report]

as you can see the date starts off from 1/2004 on my report and not 3/1932 how would i go by fixing this issue any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Below is the SQL view that i am using to populate the data set

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT CAST(DATEPART(mm, Date) AS VarChar) + '/ ' + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, Date) AS VarChar) AS Month, DATEPART(wk, Date) AS TotalWeek, Date, 
                      SUM([RM Lbs Saved]) AS [SumOfRM Lbs Saved], SUM([RM Savings $]) AS [SumOfRM Savings $]
FROM         dbo.[Net Weight Tracking Query]
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Does your report do any grouping?

Comment: Do the dates reverse in to the correct orientation if you use an "ORDER BY Date DESC"

Comment: i see grouping here. grouping will order by group first. You want no group with `order by [Date], [whatever grouping field you used]`

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes it does a Group By on the Date, i have edited the question to also include the sql view that i created to be used for the data set please take a look at that.

Comment: @LeeHarrison your right the dates only reverse in the dataset but that change does not get reflected to my report, my report behaves as though i ASC and DESC doesnt make a difference.

Comment: @Franck but i am ordering and grouping by the same date field, i want it to group by dates so i can calculate the Sums and then Order by Dates so it is in ascending order.

Comment: @HackMaster check your things because this report is definitively NOT grouped by date. Group 2 show 4 different date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently encountered a similar issue even though my query was returning the data in proper order.  If your report is based on a .rdlc report, and your report has data grouping,  The SORTING section will supersede whatever your querying data pulls down.

If so, go to your report and look at the "Row Groups" area of the report and then right-click for "Group Properties".  The "General" setting shows the "Group On" choices.  From there, confirm the grouping, then look at  the "Sorting" tab.

The sorting apparently occurs within each group, so whatever your data had come to the report with is now being sorted per the report requirements.

If your data grouping is based on the month plus year, and you have data for 3/1932, that would appear when the report gets to month 3.  What you MAY need to do is adjust the report to order by YEAR AND MONTH, so the 1932 entries come in first, then by proper month within each year.

Comment: ha nice to know that the sorting from the dataset is different from how the report sorts the data, if the dataset has grouping on it. I was also surprised to see that the Sorting was occurring by month rather than date :) it is all fixed appreciate the detailed answer :)

Comment: @HackMaster  If your .rdlc is doing sorting you can have the query return a bit faster by removing the order by.  If it is a large result set the savings can be appreciable since SQL Server (or your RDBMS) will not have to sort the results only to have the report sort them again.

Comment: @WindRaven, VERY GOOD POINT about removing the order by from the query, especially if a small dataset would be returned otherwise.

Comment: @WindRaven  Thats True, its a bit faster now, Appreciate it :)